# Is this sub-quadratic time?

Tags: algorithm, time

After analyzing an algorithm i was working on this is the running-time

```
N    Time
1000   0.019123315811157227
10000   0.11949563026428223
100000   1.4074015617370605
1000000   16.07071304321289
```

The algorithm simply returns common points in 2 2D arrays ( 'a' and 'b')

This is the code that has been used

```
def common_points(a,b): 
    start=time.time()
    specialSuperSorting(a) #Insertion Sort - ~1/4 N^2
    specialSuperSorting(b) #Insertion Sort - ~1/4 N^2
    common=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        x=a[i]
        #BinarySearch coordinates(x,y)-Returns True if found, false if not
        y=specialBinarySearch(b,x) 
        if(y):
            common.append(x)
    end=time.time()
    print(len(a),' ',end-start)
    return common
```

I know I could have used a faster sorting algorithm ... but I just took the easier path to save my time as this was just an exercise

So is this sub-quadratic time ? and how can i decide based on the table of N against T(N) only... without having the algorithm itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime of an algorithm will be dominated by its slowest component. Insertion sort is already `O(n^2)` or quadratic, so your algorithm will be at least this slow. Assuming specialBinarySearch is `O(log n)`, and you run it `n` times, this part of the algorithm will be `O(n log n)`.

In summary, your algorithm runs in `O(1/4 n^2 + 1/4 n^2 + n log n) = O(n^2)`. It's quadratic. The `1/4` doesn't change that. You can see this trend in your data, which tends upwards much faster than linear or `n log n`, if you were to plot it in a graph.

Comment: so just changing the the insertion sort to quick sort, will solve the problem right ?

Comment: @MazenSharkawy Yes, that's true for any input. However, you code might already work in subquadratic time for some input instances - check out how does insertion sort performs on almost sorted data